# Angular2 - Angular-CLI installing lodash - Cannot find module

Tags: angularjs, lodash, systemjs, npm-install, angular-cli

Mac OSX El capitan | angular-cli: 0.1.0 | node: 5.4.0 | os: darwin x64

I try to install a 3rd party npm module according to the angular-cli wiki: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs but fail. I've been struggling with this for days now and would greatly appreciate any help.

Steps to get the error:

`ng new lodashtest3
cd lodashtest3
npm install lodash --save
typings install lodash --ambient --save`

angular-cli-build.json:

`module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'lodash/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};`

`ng build`
(lodash gets correctly added in dist/vendor)

system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
 const map: any = {
   'lodash': 'vendor/lodash/lodash.js'
 };

 /** User packages configuration. */
 const packages: any = {
   'lodash': {
     format: 'cjs'
   }
 };
```

(all according to spec in 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs)
Note - I've tried all config settings I can think of here, all giving the same result.

lodashtest3.component.ts:
`import * as _ from 'lodash';`

`ng build`

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  /Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-g2lDIaq6.tmp/0/src/app/lodashtest3.component.ts (2, 20): Cannot find module 'lodash'.
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:115:19)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
    at /Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:456:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:385:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.Plugin (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:10:31)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.CachingWriter [as constructor] (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:21:10)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:26:49)
    at Angular2App._getTsTree (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:280:18)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:101:23)
    at new Angular2App (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:42:23)
    at module.exports (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/angular-cli-build.js:6:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
    at /Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/commands/build.js:32:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at /Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/danielmattsson/git/lodashtest3/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

EDIT: more information according to comments below

dist/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Lodashtest3</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Service worker support is disabled by default.
       Install the worker script and uncomment to enable.
       Only enable service workers in production.
  <script type="text/javascript">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js').catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error installing service worker: ', err);
      });
    }
  </script>
  -->
</head>
<body>
  <lodashtest3-app>Loading...</lodashtest3-app>

  <script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>

  <script>
    System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
      System.import('main');
    }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you check your dist/index.html , where lodash.js path is showing 
or can you post your dist/index.html code. I had similar problem with jquery. So I may help :)

Comment: Please check the path you provided `'lodash': 'vendor/lodash/lodash.js'` is correct ? because `npm install` will install lodash in node_modules directory

Comment: @pdfarhad I've added dist/index.html to the original post.

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja  Yes lodash is installed in node_modules, but angular-cli/webpack then puts it in dist/vendor/lodash/lodash.js. The spec (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) says 'vendor/xx' too, so I think that is correct.

Comment: perhaps duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717759/why-i-am-not-able-to-import-lodash-in-angular2]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With the stable release and current angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.15), it's simply adding the npm package plus type definitions

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev
```

**For early versions such as 1.0.0-beta.15**, the next is necessary. It should not be required for current versions:

Add the library to the `angular-cli.json` to list of global scripts (add `"../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"` to the list `apps[0].scripts`).

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation

Comment: I changed your answer to the correct one, since this is now changed as of the latest release. Thank god they made this easier :)

Comment: as of 1.0.0-beta.26 I still need to use declare const _:any; which also messes up auto-complete.

Comment: The current version of cli (`@angular/cli@1.4.4`) the process specified on @Eric Liprandi 's answer should be updated as correct as is no longer necessary to add the entire library on global (`angular-cli.json`).
Is a much better practice to add it in scope using `import ` syntax.

Answer (score 12):

FWIW, as of today (`1.0.0-beta.26`), adding the `scripts` entry is not necessary anymore.

Simply add the proper entries to `package.json` using:

```
npm i --save lodash
npm i --save-dev @types/lodash
```

Then, in your TypeScript code, use:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

The code will run just fine.

In my case, actually adding the `scripts` entry was causing issues.

Answer (score 6):

[**updated answer**] **After the new version of `angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.15):`**

just add

```
npm install lodash --save
npm install @types/lodash --save-dev
```

then add the library to the angular-cli.json to list of global scripts(add `"../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"` to the list `apps[0].scripts`).

and in your component where you want to use , try this way

```
declare var _:any;

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
  }
}
```

**before : `angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.15):`**

add this line in src/index.html

```
  <script src="/vendor/lodash/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in your component where you want to use , try this way

```
declare var _:any;

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
  }
}
```

I tried straight away , it worked for me

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes it worked and I will use it as a workaround until they get better support for 3rd party libs. 

The purpose of webpack/systemjs is to compile the libs and load them (so you don't have to add anything to index.html). However, it seems very unstable so I guess solutions like this have to do until it gets better. Thanks again!

Comment: @DanielMattsson : I updated my answer. my previous answer was for your specific question. and It was accepted by you. As the new version has came, I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

In order to support 3rd party libraries in Angular CLI and System.js, you have to specify them manually on `system.config.ts` and `angular-cli-build.js`.
I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317093/1426570) with example for `lodash` and also other dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

**As of 4/15/2017 with @angular/cli 1.0.0:**

You need to be very specific about which versions you install otherwise the TypeScript bindings will give all sorts of failures. What I did is update my devDependencies as follows in `package.json`:

```
"@types/lodash": "ts2.0"
```

Comment: This is what worked for me with 1.0.0-beta.28.3, lodash 4.15.0, @types/lodash ts2.0.