# why I am not able to import lodash in angular2

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, lodash

I am using angular-cli in angular2 rc1 for development.

I have installed lodash node_module through npm and configured it in systemjs using following:

**system.config.ts**

```
/***********************************************************************************************
* User Configuration.
**********************************************************************************************/
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/***********************************************************************************************
 * Everything underneath this line is managed by the CLI.
 **********************************************************************************************/
const barrels: string[] = [
  // Angular specific barrels.
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  'ng2-dnd',
  'ng2-bootstrap',
  'moment',
  'lodash',

  // Thirdparty barrels.
  'rxjs',

 // App specific barrels.
 'app',
 'app/shared',     
 /** @cli-barrel */
];

const cliSystemConfigPackages: any = {};
barrels.forEach((barrelName: string) => {
    if(barrelName=='ng2-dnd'){
        cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'ng2-dnd' };
    }else if (barrelName == 'ng2-bootstrap') {
        cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'ng2-bootstrap' };
    }else if (barrelName == 'lodash') {
        cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'lodash' };
    }else if (barrelName == 'moment') {
        cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'moment' };
    }else{
        cliSystemConfigPackages[barrelName] = { main: 'index' };
    }

});

/** Type declaration for ambient System. */
declare var System: any;

// Apply the CLI SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'main.js',
    'ng2-dnd': 'vendor/ng2-dnd',
    'ng2-bootstrap':'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
    'moment':'vendor/moment',
    'lodash':'vendor/lodash'
 },
 meta: {
    lodash: { format: 'amd' }
 },  
 packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});

// Apply the user's configuration.
System.config({ map, packages });
```

I would just like to note that other node_modules are working correctly i.e. moment,ng2-bootstrap etc.
**angular-cli-build.js**

```
/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
   return new Angular2App(defaults, {
     vendorNpmFiles: [
       'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
       'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
       'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
       'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
       'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
       'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
       '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
       'ng2-dnd/**/*.js',
       'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
       'moment/*.js',
       'lodash/*.js'
     ]
   });
 };
```

after this configuration of lodash node_module, I am importing it from the directory `dist\vendors\lodash`

in my app.component i am importing it as :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

But I am getting below error:

> Cannot find module 'lodash'

any solutions?
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added below tag in index.html?   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.0/lodash.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Sanket tried adding that,still not working

Comment: See if you can get some help from this - https://github.com/jamesemann/ng2-vscode-template

Comment: Why did you put it in the angular specific list?

Comment: @brianlmerritt it doesnt matter, its just an array ,moment & ng2-bootstrap are working fine

Comment: you can check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712677/angular2-angular-cli-installing-lodash-cannot-find-module/37718379#37718379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you a workaround until they get better support for 3rd party libs. It worked for me :)

In your angular-cli-build.json , make sure it remains like this way

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...
      'lodash/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

and in your system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
 const map: any = {
   'lodash': 'vendor/lodash/lodash.js'
 };

 /** User packages configuration. */
 const packages: any = {
   'lodash': {
     format: 'cjs'
   }
 };
```

in your src/index.html add this line

```
 <script src="/vendor/lodash/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now in your component where you want to use lodash , write this way

```
declare var _:any;

@Component({
})
export class YourComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same and is not working U_U In my `vendor/lodash` folder there are a lot of `.js` files and not the `lodash.js`

Comment: Did you `npm install lodash --save`

Comment: yes. But not exist `lodash.js`; there are a lot of files: clone.js, compact.js, concat.js, curry.js, etc.

Comment: can you show your screenshot  of node_module folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```