# Error: Cannot find module 'lodash' in angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

#### **OS**

Mac OSX  El Capitan

#### **Versions**

`angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.8` ,  `node: 6.2.0`, `os: darwin x64`

#### **Description**

I tried to add `lodash` library in angular-cli project:

- `npm install --save lodash`
- `typings install lodash --global --save`

Successfully installed in `node_modules`.

**system-config.ts**:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'lodash': 'vendor/lodash',
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'lodash': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'core.js'
  }
};
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'lodash/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

And then I tried to import in a service in different ways:

1. `import { chunk, intersection, zip } from 'lodash';`

   ```
   Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
   ```
2. `declare var _;`
   `const {chunk, intersection, zip} = _;`

   ```
    Error: Cannot find name 'chunk'
           Cannot find name 'intersection'
           Cannot find name 'zip'
   ```

I don't found the way to use `lodash`...

*I did something wrong? I miss something? Is there an issue?*

Thank you very much,

Aral.

---

#### Similar questions *(but don't answer my question)*:

- [Angular2 - Angular-CLI installing lodash - Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712677/angular2-angular-cli-installing-lodash-cannot-find-module)
- [How to add bootstrap to an angular-cli project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649164/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project)

#### Official docs:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

Comment: you can see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712677/angular2-angular-cli-installing-lodash-cannot-find-module/37718379#37718379

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `system-config.ts` to:

```
const map: any = {
  'lodash': 'vendor/lodash',
};

const packages: any = {
  'lodash': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  }
};
```

And then import it as:

```
import 'lodash';
declare var _;
```

Finally use it as:

```
_.chunk();
```

Comment: `import 'lodash';
declare var _;`
This worked for me - did not even set format in packages.
The `import * as _ from 'lodash';` syntax worked perfectly on Plunker... any explanation?

Comment: @ootwch Plunkr link?

Comment: Here you go - this plunker is not designed to demonstrate this, this is just one of my experiments. https://plnkr.co/edit/kAcaV16mlXrso8jWpq8C?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

@codef0rmer answer is good, but if you want specific `lodash` dependencies and not the whole library, here is an answer with example on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38317093/1426570