# Cannot find module 'md5' on Importing vendorNpmFile ts-md5

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Might be duplicate of Ref : [Angular2 - Angular-CLI installing lodash - Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712677/angular2-angular-cli-installing-lodash-cannot-find-module) but didn't work for me

Followed https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs to import ts-md using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5

Imported ts-md5 using npm install ts-md5 --save on node_modules. My configuration in my angular-cli setup is

package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
  ......
  "ts-md5": "^1.2.0"
}
```

anular-cli-build config :

```
 var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');
 var mergeTree = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
 module.exports = function(defaults) {
 let appTree = new Angular2App(defaults, {
 sassCompiler: {
  cacheExclude: [/\/_[^\/]+$/]
 },
 vendorNpmFiles: [
   ....
  'ts-md5/dist/md5.js'
 ]
 })
 return mergeTree([appTree], { overwrite: true });
 };
```

On ng build i could find md5 file imported inside vendor/ts-md5/dist/md5.js

system-config.ts :

```
const map: any = {
  'moment' : 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
  'ng2-bootstrap' : 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
  '@angular2-material': 'vendor/@angular2-material',
  'd3' : 'vendor/d3',
  'md5': 'vendor/ts-md5/dist/md5.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'moment' : {
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  'ng2-bootstrap' : {   
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'd3' : {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'd3.min.js'
  },
  'md5': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'md5.js'
  }
};
```

Included **import * as md5 from 'md5'** on my companent to import ts-md5.

On ng build i get Cannot find module 'md5'

```
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
GitRepo/app-web/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-zurkjkU9.tmp/0/src/app/shared/gravatar/gravatar.component.ts (3, 22): Cannot find module 'md5'.
at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._doIncrementalBuild (/GitRepo/app-web/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:120:19)
at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (/GitRepo/app-web/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/broccoli-typescript.js:43:10)
at /GitRepo/app-web/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:152:21
```

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> install this module.

```
npm install ts-md5 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your typings.d.ts

`declare module 'md5' {
  var exportAs:any;
  export = exportAs;
}`

Comment: Getting Module ''md5'' has no exported mng 'md5' for most of the npm md5 packages